# How was this menu system created?

Tags: menus, navigation, front-end, sub-menu, user-interface

Can anyone give me a clue how this menu system was created?

https://40thdems.org/

This is a WordPress site using the Divi theme.  Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: What makes you think it's not just Divi?

Comment: Maybe it is - but I don't know how to make "flippy" animated menus like this with Divi.

Answer (score 0):

You can create that flip effect by setting the dropdown animation to Flip in your WordPress Dashboard > Divi > Theme Customizer > Header & Navigation > Primary Menu Bar

All the way at the bottom is DROPDOWN MENU ANIMATION

Set that to "Flip"